# Is a Try/Catch Redundant in a Node.js MySQL Query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, try-catch

I am setting up a system that will query a MySQL database for registering and deleting staff and such. I was just wondering if there is a need to have the query in a try catch block or if it is simply redundant. I have an example below. My understanding is that this will throw an error but not crash the system as it will, as a try/catch does, catch the error and let the server remain functional.

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'mysql1',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'assignment',
  password: 'admin'
});

let sqlQuery = `INSERT INTO CBOdb (staffName, staffID, staffPassword, time) VALUES ('${staffName}', '${staffID}', '${staffPassword}', NOW())`;

try {
  con.query(sqlQuery, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      res.send(0)
    }
  })
} catch {
  res.send(1) //"**Error ecounterd, staff not registerd**\nPlease contact system Administrator.")
}
```

Comment: Using a promise based db driver will simplify this. Whichever driver you are using my already support promises even

Comment: @charlietfl, could you perhaps give a simple example?  Sorry I know about promises for the most part but do not entirely know the proper usage in this case.

Comment: Based on the callback function, yes, I think the `try/catch` is redundant. Errors should all go through your `if (err)`. If you were using something like `promisify` to turn `con.query` into a promise, and you were using `async/await` syntax, then you might need the `try/catch`. But as it stands, probably not.

Comment: which package are you currently using?

Comment: @charlietfl I am using express currently.

Comment: But as far as I know express does not have it's own mysql driver and you would be using another npm package

Comment: @charlietfl Oh really? Oh I mean im also using the mySQL package and then ofc node but thats about it. This is just what I initially used in my class, using things like `app.post()` and then using the outcome to call a `con.query()`

Comment: Right but there are mutliple different npm mysql packages around

Comment: ah I see, well when I install it I am just running `npm install mysql --save` So I would say just the base package. Along with I am running mysql version 5.7.31.

Comment: Depending on the source of the variables you might want to have a look at: https://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is a Try/Catch Redundant in this Node.js MySQL Query?

Yes, it is unnecessary.  Errors from the query are not communicated back via synchronous exceptions that you can catch with `try/catch`.  They are communicated back via the `err` argument to the callback.

As has been mentioned in the comments, there are a couple different versions of the mysql module for nodejs.  You are using the original version based on plain callbacks.  There is another version of the module named [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) that supports promises and this gives you some more modern ways of calling mysql and handling errors using promises, `await` and `try/catch`.

Here's an example of using `await` and catching errors with try/catch using the mysql2/promise interface.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');


app.get("/somePath", async (req, res) => {

    // this needs to be inside an async function so you can use await

    const con = await mysql.createConnection({ ... });
    let sqlQuery = `INSERT INTO CBOdb (staffName, staffID, staffPassword, time) VALUES ('${staffName}', '${staffID}', '${staffPassword}', NOW())`;
    
    try {
      const result = await con.query(sqlQuery);
      res.send(0)
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      res.send(1); //"**Error ecounterd, staff not registerd**\nPlease contact system Administrator.")
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a controller/service/repo-like architecture, you should use `try/catch` in the first two but in the repo (the layer that connects to your database through an ORM-like sequelize) you can just use the ORM methods to find/update/destroy entries in your database, the ORM will handle database errors and your app won't crash.